# RaphaelJS - Animating connections

Tags: javascript, raphael

I've done something similar to this:
http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html

However, I am animating the boxes on click of a button. Basically I am moving the boxes around on animation. The problem now is when I animate the boxes, the connections do not move along. Is there a way I can animate the connections along with the boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. Use the code inside the move function on your function (the part with connections.push bla bla bla).

This one:

```
   for (var i = connections.length; i--;) {
        r.connection(connections[i]);
    }
```

Insert that on every step of your animate function. (That is from the default version... if you made changes adapt it).

That will recreate the connections between your nodes at the new position.

Comment: I get that. How do I get a callback on every step of the animate function?

Comment: Depends on how you did the animate. How you did it?

Comment: Thus is how I did:
`shape.animate({x: 500 }, 500, ">");`

Comment: Yeah... you have a problem there. There is a workaround tho... not bulletproof but quite ok if you make it right. Made another animating function for the connections (the old fashion pure js way). (a function with a timout to a wait that goes to self.).

Comment: Thats a good idea. So there seems no way to get a callback on each step in Raphael animation.

Comment: Not really... Or if you find a way without modifieng the library tell me (I tried also).